# Deleting a SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-delete

I am still relatively new to SQL. I created a view previously and I am trying to delete the view. The view is named `Sales` and the db is 'dbo'. I keep getting this error :

> Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   View or function 'dbo.Sales' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

My code is this:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Sales]
WHERE SOHNUM_0 IN  ('SO004025', 'SO000942', 'SO003772', 'SO005501', 'SO005523')
GO
```

The view contains `SOHNUM` (sales order number) and `SOHDAT` (order date). The version is SQL Server 2012.

The select statement is:

```
Select * from [dbo].[Sales];
```

and the result set is:

```
 SOHNUM     SOHDAT
 ----------------------------------------
 SO004025   2030-07-25 00:00:00.000
 SO000942   2018-12-17 00:00:00.000
 SO003772   2017-01-10 00:00:00.000
 SO005501   2017-01-03 00:00:00.000
 SO005523   2017-01-03 00:00:00.000
 SO005523   2017-01-03 00:00:00.000
 SO005523   2017-01-03 00:00:00.000
 SO005523   2017-01-03 00:00:00.000
 SO005523   2017-01-03 00:00:00.000
 SO005523   2017-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: What is the definition of the view...not the select statement to read data from it.

Comment: so wait are you wanting to delete data from the view, or delete the view, or eliminate some of the data from the view's output?  If the last, `select * from dbo.sales where sohnum_0 not in  ('SO004025','SO000942','SO003772','SO005501','SO005523')` would exclude the reocrds, drop view dbo.sales would delete the view. and if you're trying to delete particualr records from the view.... well you can't you have to delete from the source tables. (unless the view is based on 1 and only 1 table)

Comment: Recommendations:  (1) Don't delete from views.  (2) Name views to distinguish them from base tables.

Answer (score 4):

It would be helpful to see the `SELECT` statement which defines the view, but I think the error is pretty clear: you can't delete from this view because the view reads data from multiple tables. You can use an INSTEAD OF trigger to handle deletes against this view, but without knowing the database and its intended use it would be difficult to advise on how best to handle this.

Best of luck.

Comment: How is dbo.Sales defined?

Answer (score 0):

Very few views meet all the rules that allow you to update or delete from them directly. Your view does not meet the rules. There for the best bet is to do what you should have done originally and delete directly from the base tables.

Comment: If as seems likely, your tables are related, then you need to delete from the child tables first.  Of course deleting from anything titled SALES is generally a bad idea.